# How do I get aggro of a boss who is immune to taunts?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the new Rakata Prime flashpoint and in the Karagga's Palace Operation there are multiple bosses that are untauntable. Is there any way to get them to attack me or do they randomly attack enemys?

They all have a buff that says: `Immune to taunts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colonel Darok and the Rancor handler (War Chief Rehkta) in Legacy of the Rakata have no threat tables; they attack players or companions or NPCs more or less at random.

In Karagga's Palace, Bonethrasher behaves similarly to the above.  Foreman Crusher has a mechanic where he will attack a member of the group (usually whoever has the second most threat) and a taunt can return him to you after the initial knockback on that player.

Other untauntable Operations bosses include Dread Master Tyrans in the final Dread Palace fight*, Cartel Warlords Captain Horic and Vilus Garr in Scum and Villainy, Dread Guard Heirad in Terror from Beyond, and (while he is Berserk) Zorn in Explosive Conflict.  Flashpoint bosses include the final cyber-Selkath — Stivastin — in Depths of Manaan, and (while he is firing rockets at another group member) Chief Zokar in Czerka Corporate Labs.  There are many many bosses with mechanics where they will attack someone without threat temporarily, or reset their aggro tables, without becoming immune to taunts.

As noted in one of the other answers, threat is 1:1 with damage done except for tanks — normal moves are 2:1 and high-threat moves, such as the Juggernaut's Backhand, are even more.  Healing does lesser threat (45% of the amount healed) and there are talents to further reduce it, but it applies to all enemies; this causes new spawns to target the healers first.  Guarding a player will redirect some of their threat towards you.

All classes (though not some tank roles) also have abilities to reduce or wipe their threat.  Taunts force the enemy to attack you for 6 seconds and, within melee range, give you 110% of the highest threat any player has on the target; if you are further away, you get 130%.

<sup>*You can gain threat on Tyrans by getting the crystal at the top of his throne.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A boss will almost always Aggro the target which generated the highest amount of threat. Usually for DPS classes the threat ration is 1:1 with damage, however for tank classes you have a higher threat ratio while there are also spells that generate a lot more threat (Crushing Blow and Backhand as a Juggernaut for example) so you can try using these as often as possible.

Other than that you can also generate threat by Buffing and Healing allies and by Debuffing the enemy target.

Note that there are also sometimes threat Resets which means you need to rebuild your tanking threat and sometimes bosses completely ignore threat and they just attack a random player (not much you can do about this).

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean Dark Arkous and Colonel Darok?

[Dulfy](http://dulfy.net/2014/09/09/swtor-rakata-prime-flashpoint/) doesn't say anything about untauntable, but something about the random attack:

> Another tank and spank fight like the first boss encounter. Darth Arkous has some kind of burst attack that can deal a lot of damage so might be good to kill him first. Colonel Darok will grapple random players to him but doesn’t do much otherwise.

From my knowledge of swtor I think I can say that the tank can hold aggro if properly geared and doing the right rotation for his class. In the beginning of the battle it can be a bit hard  but if the tank gets a headstart, it shouldn't be a problem. All dps should attack the target of the tank, of course.